# Error al visualizar los paquetes de la version de angular

Tags: angular, cli

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Alguien podria, ayudarme a como solucionar este, error, ya proble reinstalando todo desde nod, typescript y angular, y me sale lo mismo, al ver la version global de angular, los paquetes me marcan errror

Comment: Hola Wat, bienvenido. ¿Puedes [edit] la pregunta y añadir los comandos y los errores que te aparecen? Te recomiendo completar el [tour] para comprender qué se considera una buena pregunta, si no añades detalles es complicado ayudarte.

Comment: Pablo Lozano, subi una imagen del error...

Comment: Intenta evitar subir imágenes, es mejor copiar y pegar texto

Answer (score 0):

Sólo puedes ver las versiones de las librerías usadas en el proyecto actual. Por tanto tienes que estar en el directorio raíz de dicho proyecto (donde esté `angular.json` y `package.json`). Por lo que veo en tu captura, estás en `C:\Windows\system32`. Es normal que te muestre un error.

Comment: Pablo Lozano, ya entre a la carpeta donde tengo un proyecto que cree previamente y me arroja el mismo error, de echo al levantar el servidor con ng server -o me marca error

Comment: ¿Tienes esos ficheros en la carpeta?

Comment: Si, de echo desde me marca el error desde la consola de comando y desde visual code

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
Require stack:
- C:\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js
- C:\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js
- C:\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js
- C:\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\index.js
- C:\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js
esto son alguno de los errores q me marca en visual code

Comment: ¿Tienes el proyecto creado en raíz?

Comment: Si C:\proyangularspring\angular\clientes

Comment: Me refería a `C:\ ` ... no entiendo por qué tienes una carpeta `c:\node_modules`, si el proyecto está en `c:\proyectoangular....` es ahí donde deberían estar las dependencias y el directorio `node_modules`

Comment: hay alguna forma de desinstalar todo, para volver a instalarlo de nuevo, instale node, typescrip y despues angular

Comment: borra las carpetas de node_modules en raíz

Comment: amigo borre el de la raiz, el node... pero aun me carga el error en el typescript

Comment: @angular-devkit/build-angular y typescript, en esos dos paquetes me marca errror